# Android send HTML mail through Exchange

Tags: android, html, email, exchange-server, smtpclient

My application sends a HTML email with very basic tags: DIV, P and A.

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.sharing_data));
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share data:"));
```

If it send through Gmail it works perfectly.
But most of the users send it through Exchange the email is received without links.

**Can I solve that in Android or I need to do something in the Exchange side ?**

Comment: `Html.fromHtml` does not return an HTML String. Therefore The links are only present if the client application adds them.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: The String `body` contains the html tags? Then you don't need `Html.fromHtml`, I think

Comment: No, it puts the html as plain text.

Comment: strange, since the type is clearly `text/html`. possibly the mail editor that rejects html